# Why doesn't `dd` create partitions when copying the Raspberry Pi disk image?

Tags: setup

I'm trying to install one image of the download page of the Raspberry Pi [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads), but when executing the steps on the page after the `dd` command, it does not create the partitions on the SD card. Am I missing any steps?

What I have tried:

1. Using GParted to delete all partitions and set the state of the SD card to non-formatted.
2. `df -h` to view the devices
3. `umount` it if listed
4. execute `sudo dd bs=1M if=~/roottofile/2012-08-16-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/sdb1`

Shouldn't there be partitions on the SD card after this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is wrong.

You should execute

```
sudo dd bs=1M if=~/roottofile/2012-08-16-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/sdb
```

`/dev/sdb1` is the first partition of the SD card. `/dev/sdb` is the block device of the SD card itself.

Personally, I'd kick up `bs` to `4M`.

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=~/roottofile/2012-08-16-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: Yes, right! if was wrong with the of=/sd/sdb1.. Thanks. The bs param as in the doc is 1M, i did not know what would happen when swtiched to 4M. Did you know it?

Comment: I did know and I still do. It will write 4M at a time instead of 1M. It's more efficient as the erase block of the SD card is probably 4M. Might not be the case on all computers and cards.